# Bootstrap ab-datepicker "onUpdate" function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to use the [accessible bootstrap datepicker](http://eureka2.github.io/ab-datepicker/) but I'm running into issues with either detecting when the date changes or just getting the date at all.

First, the onUpdate function in the [docs](https://github.com/eureka2/ab-datepicker#methods) says you should be able to detect when the date is changed. However, nothing is printed to the console when I change the date with the following code:

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onUpdate: function (value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

No console errors though, just nothing happens. What's wrong with that piece of code?

Second, I don't actually know how to access the date from the datepicker at all. I've tried the following:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().getDate();
$("#datepicker").datepicker().date
$("#datepicker").getDate();
$("#datepicker").datepicker().value();
```

I'm just hunting around in the dark because the docs don't actually say how to get the date, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change and onUpdate functions are not working for accessible bootstrap datepicker. but you can use below code as workaround.

```
$('#date').change(function(){ console.log($(this).val()); });
```